# Can't Create 1 instances of sphere in structs

Tags: c++, reference, struct, constants

```
#include <iostream>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

//the volume and surface area of sphere

struct sphere_t { float radius; }; 
sphere_t sph; 
sph.radius = 3; // this is the part that mess me up, error in sph.radius

double SphereSurfaceArea(const sphere_t &sph)
{
    return 4*M_PI*sph.radius*sph.radius; 
}

double SphereVolume(const sphere_t &sph)
{
    return 4.0/3.0*M_PI*sph.radius*sph.radius*sph.radius;
}

int main()
{

    cout << "Sphere's description: " << sph.radius << endl;
    cout << "Surface Area: " << SphereSurfaceArea(sph) << endl; 
    cout << "Volume :" <<SphereVolume(sph) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

The output I get is:

> The solid's description The surface area The volume

How can i put a number in a const function by constant reference and set the function void without return anything?

Comment: Can you reformat your question ? It is not understandable for the moment...

Comment: You can't do what you're asking.  The only way to get a return value via an argument is if the argument is passed by non-const reference.

Comment: where is `sph` declared?

Comment: For some reason I very much doubt that you get any output out of the code you've shown us, unless you're referring to compiler output.

Comment: @stardust_ `sphere_t sph;`

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the initialization into one line together with the definition of your global variable:

```
sphere_t sph = { 3 };
```

Answer (score 2):

This

```
sph.radius = 3;
```

is an assignment statement, it assigns the value of 3 to sph.radius. It's a rule of C++ that assignment statements can only go in functions. You've written one outside of a function.

I would write your code like this

```
int main()
{
    sphere_t sph; 
    sph.radius = 3;

    cout << "Sphere's description: " << sph.radius << endl; 
    cout << "Surface Area: " << SphereSurfaceArea(sph) << endl; 
    cout << "Volume :" << SphereVolume(sph) << endl;

    system("pause");
    return(0);
}
```

Now the assignment (and the declaration of sph) are inside the function main.